# HERE-SDK (hello_map_app problem) Lost connection to device. It is larger than the device screen size

Tags: android, flutter, here-api, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

- I used the basic example given [here](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter/hello_map_app) (by developer.here.com documentation).
- I set two of my SDK information correctly as it's shown in the documentation.
- I placed the HERE SDK plugin in the plugins folder.
- *I used Flutter 1.20.2, Dart version 2.9.1 as it's recommended in developer.here.com documentation.* But moreover I got the same error with higher versions of flutter.

I also tried with:

- Pixel 3 XL API 30 (1440x2960; 560dpi, android 11 x86)
- Pixel 4 API 29 (1080x2280; 440 dpi, android 10 x86)

**I got the following error on both phones.** The application opens on the device and then closes.

Why am I still getting the same error? (It is larger than the device screen size. | Lost connection to device.)

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
 lib\main.dart
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:51802/8_7jdsOFG8I=/ws
D/EGL_emulation(11629): eglMakeCurrent: 0xeaa800c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc6a07b90)
D/eglCodecCommon(11629): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
W/PlatformViewsController(11629): Creating a virtual display of size: [1080, 2148] may result in problems(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/2897).It is larger than the device screen size: [1080, 1977].
I/harp-sdk(11629): [INFO ] harp-sdk - Initializing SDK renderer with a threaded render loop
I/harp-sdk(11629): [INFO ] harp-sdk - Starting renderer
I/harp-sdk(11629): [INFO ] harp-sdk - Render loop thread created
I/harp-sdk(11629): [INFO ] harp-sdk - Renderer started
I/harp-sdk(11629): [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
I/harp-sdk(11629): [INFO ] harp-sdk - Starting render loop thread (state=<paused>)
W/Gralloc3(11629): allocator 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection(11629): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb2991d70, tid 11851
D/HostConnection(11629): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
D/eglCodecCommon(11629): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(11629): eglCreateContext: 0xb29d50a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation(11629): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb29d50a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc6a11b50)
I/magma-graphics-opengl(11629): [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Vendor string: Google (NVIDIA Corporation)
I/magma-graphics-opengl(11629): [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Renderer string: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2)
I/magma-graphics-opengl(11629): [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - OpenGL ES 2.0
I/magma-graphics-opengl(11629): [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_robustness GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan
I/magma-graphics-opengl(11629): _shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2
I/magma-graphics-opengl(11629): [INFO ] magma-graphics-opengl - Parsed OpenGL GPU info string - VendorId=Unknown ModelFamily= ModelCode=0
E/CL_magma(11629): [ERROR] CL_magma - Couldn't get context config: no error
I/CL_magma(11629): [INFO ] CL_magma - Failed to set rendering parameters with anti-aliasing. Will retry without anti-aliasing.
D/eglCodecCommon(11629): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation(11629): eglCreateContext: 0xb29d5280: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation(11629): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb29d5280: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc6a11b50)
E/CL_magma(11629): [ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Primitive.shaderb'
E/CL_magma(11629): [ERROR] CL_magma - Unable to open shader file 'shaders/gles2.0/Default.shaderb'
E/CL_magma(11629): [ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'spot_light_glow.rgba4.tex'
E/CL_magma(11629): [ERROR] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'light_flare.rgba4.tex'
F/CL_magma(11629): [FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.
F/libc    (11629): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 11851 (Thread-45), pid 11629 (amples.hellomap)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.190920.001/5891938:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2020-12-22 18:15:57+0300
pid: 11629, tid: 11851, name: Thread-45  >>> com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap <<<
uid: 10134
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL] CL_magma - Couldn't load the default shader.'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00002d6d  ecx 00002e4b  edx 00000006
    edi f324733e  esi b18f2a60
    ebp f5ff8ad0  esp b18f2a08  eip f5ff8ad9
backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000ad9  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
      #01 pc 00092328  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
      #02 pc 000ad651  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+193) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
      #03 pc 013f588a  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #04 pc 00c218d2  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #05 pc 00c1e094  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #06 pc 00bf7447  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #07 pc 00bf7594  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #08 pc 00840f3e  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #09 pc 0083ef37  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #10 pc 004955a1  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #11 pc 00497943  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #12 pc 004a5329  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #13 pc 004a734d  /data/app/com.here.sdk.examples.hellomap-9dSK-6YhdIbYjYLCM5Gang==/lib/x86/libheresdk.so (BuildId: 328f1be8ae7052e051b45d31ec8eb51a65d71339)
      #14 pc 0011a8e5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
      #15 pc 000af6a7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

```
[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.20.2 at D:\Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision bbfbf1770c (4 months ago), 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
    • Engine revision 9d5b21729f
    • Dart version 2.9.1

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Flutter\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\MSİ\.android\avd
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Flutter\Sdk
    • Java binary at: D:\Flutter\AndroidStudio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at D:\Flutter\AndroidStudio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = D:\Flutter\AndroidStudio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.2)
    • IntelliJ at D:\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3
    • Flutter plugin version 42.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Web Server (web)                   • web-server    • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome [HIDDEN IP]
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge [HIDDEN IP]
```

[image: problems]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue solved by adding this to gradle.properties file in android folder

```
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false
```

By referring [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72185).